# How to display Timestamps as per User's location in cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hi I am using Razor as template for my .net applications.
Currently I am displaying time by @DateTime.Now.ToString("f").
Please help me how can I display date time specific to end user's zone in razor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this keyword

local time depends on where the computer is located. The universal time is independent of this

```
    @DateTime.UtcNow;



    TimeZone zone =  TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
    // Demonstrate ToLocalTime and ToUniversalTime.
    DateTime local = zone.ToLocalTime(DateTime.Now);
    DateTime universal = zone.ToUniversalTime(DateTime.Now);
```